# Image from Master Page Disappears when Putting .aspx Page in a Folder

Tags: asp.net, html, master-pages

I know this is probably a stupid question but I can't find anything on here about it. I have a master page in the root of my solution explorer and just put an .aspx page in a new folder. The master page is referencing an image in another folder and when I preview the page, it's a broken image. What do I have to do to have the page load the image from a master page? Thanks

Comment: fix your relative path of the image, and it will `just work` !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use relative path. Below is an example:

```
<asp:Image ImageUrl="~/Images/orderedList1.png" runat="server" />
<img src="~/Images/orderedList0.png" runat="server" />
```

Don't forget to add runat="server" if you don't use asp.net control

Comment: Yes I was simply adding the image into the project, forgetting to actually make an asp image or making it runat server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, by not posting the markup with the reference to the image, you leave us to guess what's happening.

But how about this: you only have a partial (relative) path to the image, and that path is not valid from the location of your aspx file.

Did I guess right?

Comment: It can be. But it's sub-optimal for resolving issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may be referencing the image with no path.

When a child page is loaded in a MasterPage, the "current" directory changes to the child page's directory.  So the relative path has changed.